# append data in csv, but determine the rows and columns yourself

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to ask, how do you append data in csv, but determine the rows and columns yourself? maybe someone has an example?
[image]

Comment: Hi, please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples to improve your question.

Comment: Please share your code. Have you tried the `csv` library?

Comment: A `csv` is a text file.  If you open the file in append mode, you can write any text to it.  Whether the result can be read by a regular csv-reader is another matter.  I'm not sure what your display is?  excel?

Comment: What do you mean by "but determine the rows and columns yourself?" how do you want to determine the rows and columns?

Answer (score 0):

There is `df.loc`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[111, 'Hi'], ['Hello', 222], [333, 'Ahoy']],
     columns=['Number', 'String'])

print(df)

    Number  String
0   111     Hi
1   Hello   222
2   333     Ahoy


# set row 1, column 'Number' to 222
df.loc[1, 'Number'] = 222
# set row 1, column 'String' to Hello
df.loc[1, 'String'] = 'Hello'

print('\n', df)

    Number  String
0   111     Hi
1   222     Hello
2   333     Ahoy
```

Unless it is a minor correction there are probably better ways.